# How to remove quotes from each element in a javascript array containing JSON encoded html strings returned from a mysql database with php

Tags: php, html, json, ajax, quotes

Ajax call to the mysql data base using data1.php file with pdo returns hmtl strings that are put into an array, encoded with json and sent to the ajax response function for display in html. Of course the elements in the array have tags and quotations, which are difficult to remove. Easiest and closest solution so far is to replace the quotes in the strings with javascript .replace(). This doesn't work for the array of arrays unless the single element is referenced. What's the way around this? Here is the code.

Ajax call:

```
function processForm_L(){
var topic = $("#topic").val();
// send data
$.ajax({
  url: "../php/get_data1.php",
  data: {
  topic1:topic},
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: processResult_L
}); // end .onclick
}
```

The response function:

```
function processResult_L(data, textStatus){
    // Required Callback Function
    if(data['status']['response'] == 1){
        //if(data[0] == 1){
        table_1 = [];
        table_2 = [];
        table_3 = [];

        table_1 = data.table['a'].replace( /"/g,"");
        table_2 = data.data.replace(/"/g,"");
        table_3 = data.table['b'].replace( /"/g,"");

        //table_1 = JSON.parse(data.table['a']);
        //table_2 = JSON.parse(data.data);
        //table_3 = JSON.parse(data.table['b']);
        //console.log(table_1);
        console.log(table_2);
        //console.log(table_3);
    }//end if response == 1

    else if(data.response == 0){
        //var response = data + textStatus;
        var table_4 = data.error;
        $('#display').html(table_4);
    }//end if response==0
}//end process results
```

The query part of get_data1.php

```
<?php
$ret_s = Array();//return status
$ret_t = Array();//return table
$ret_d = Array();//return data
$result = Array();
$row_1 = 1;

if(!empty($_POST)){

    try{

        if(!empty($_POST)){
            //connect to database and insert data
            //      include "db_connect_df.php";

            // select everything from the raw_data database
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM `raw_data`";

        // prepare the sql statement
        $stmt_s =  $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt_s->execute();
        $result = $stmt_s->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        //set response variable
        $ret_s['response'] = 1;

        //table header
        $ret_t['a'] ="<table    id='display_table'><tr><th>ID</th><th>Organization</th><th>Contact Names</th><th>Telephone</th><th>Email</th><th>Website</th><th>Country</th><th>Region</th><th>City</th><th>Street</th><th>Unit</th><th>Postal Code</th><th>Topic</th><th>Message</th><th>Date</th></tr>";

        //fetch each row from database as html
        foreach($result as $row){
            $ret_d[$row_1] = "<tr>" ."<td>" . $row['ID'] . "</td>" ."<td>" .
            $row['Organization'] . "</td>" ."<td>" . $row['Telephone'] . "</td>" . "<td>" . $row['Email'] . "</td>" ."<td>" . $row['Website'] . "</td>" ."<td>" . $row['Country'] . "</td>" ."<td>" . $row['Region'] . "</td>" ."<td>" . $row['City'] . "</td>" ."<td>" . $row['Street'] . "</td>" ."<td>" . $row['Unit'] . "</td>" ."<td>" . $row['Postal_Code'] . "</td>" ."<td>" . $row['Topic'] . "</td>" ."<td>" . $row['Message'] . "</td>" ."<td>" . $row['ts'] . "</td>" ."</tr>";
            $row_1++;
        }
        // end table tag
        $ret_t['b'] = "</table>";

        //echo and encode array
        echo json_encode(array('status' => $ret_s, 'table' => $ret_t,'data'=> $ret_d),JSON_HEX_QUOT|JSON_HEX_TAG);


        // echo json_encode(stripslashes_nested(array('status' => $ret_s, 'table' => $ret_t,'data'=> $ret_d)),JSON_HEX_QUOT|JSON_HEX_TAG);
        }//end connect
    }//end try 

    catch (PDOException $e) {
        $error16 = '<span class="error_s">Try again another time.</span>';
        $error17 = '<span class="error_s">ERROR:' . $e->getMessage();
        $ret_s['response'] = 0;
        $ret_s['error'] = $error16 . $error17;
        echo json_encode($ret_s);    
    } //end failure
}//end if is !empty($_POST)
?>
```

Note: this queries a localhost database served through xampp. This isn't all the code but everything works just fine except the following:

1) `table_2 = data.data.replace(/"/g,"");` returns 'data.data.replace() is not a function, because the array is an object not a string

2) when comment out above line and comment in only `console.log(table_1);` result in console is:

`<table id='display_table'><tr><th>ID</th><th>Organization</th><th>Contact Names</th><th>Telephone</th><th>Email</th><th>Website</th><th>Country</th><th>Region</th><th>City</th><th>Street</th><th>Unit</th><th>Postal Code</th><th>Topic</th><th>Message</th><th>Date</th></tr>` So that works.

3) similarly commenting in only `console.log(table_3);` returns in console:

`</table>` so that also works.

4) if comment in `table_2 = data.data;`  and enter table_2 into console result is:

`undefined`

5) tried this code to remove quotes from the array of arrays:

a) putting a function in the js init file for the page:

```
function replace_quotes(x){
for(var i=0; i < x.length; i++) {
 x[i] = x[i].toString().replace(/"/g,"");
}
}
```

and using that function on the data array in the data object created by the response callback function (so x = data.data)

result is undefined, and it doesn't work.

`JSON.parse(table_1);` just runs into a `<` right away and won't parse, for any of the strings in the data array (table_2 or table 3).

adding `JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_TAG` didn't work.

Presumably looping through the array data.data with a function and using .replace() and a reg exp to replace quotes with nothing should be the easiest solution. Any tips on how to loop through a json_encoded array of html strings in an array returned in an ajax callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't replace anything anywhere. The only thing you need is to add `htmlspecialchars()` when you building the HTML string.

```
<?php
// ...
$rows = [];
foreach ($result as $r) {
    $rows[] = '<tr><td>'.htmlspecialchars($r['id'])
        .'</td><td>'.htmlspecialchars($r['phone_number'])
        .'</td></tr>';
}
header('Content-Type: application/json; encoding=utf-8');
echo json_encode(array('table_rows' => join("\n", $rows)));
```

Then, when you receive such JSON, just put it into HTML as it is.

```
$('table#display').html(received_data.table_rows);
```

But there is better way to implement this. -- Send only data without markup via JSON and build markup in JS:

```
<?php
// ...
$rows = [];
foreach ($result as $r) {
    $rows[] = [
        'id' => $r['id'],
        'phone_number' => $r['phone_number']
    ];
}
header('Content-Type: application/json; encoding=utf-8');
echo json_encode(array('table_rows' => $rows));
```

And then:

```
// ...
for(var i = 0; i < received_data.table_rows.length; i++) {
    var r = received_data.table_rows[i];
    $table.append($('<tr>')
        .append($('td').text(r.id))
        .append($('td').text(r.phone_number))
    );
}
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks. Rather than testing .htmlspecialchars() on the original php, moved form construction over to client side and built jquery dom elements. Added switch statements to both php and javascript init, to select different queries from the table.

Comment: There is some nonsense to replace null values with a string in the mysql queries, which could probably be done more efficiently in php row build function, but it works. Below case 0 of the switch statements and working code for others to view.

Comment: Technically, the question was not answered, but a better method was provided. Presumably, to remove the double quotes from the json data returned via the ajax call one could use the for loop provided above and loop through the second dimension array with .replace().

Answer (score 0):

PHP case 0, file called from ajax dropdown selector form submission:

```
if(!empty($_POST)){
//connect to database and insert data
//      include "db_connect_df.php";
include "db_connect_df_test.php";
//switch statement for mysql queries based on dropdown selected
switch($topic_2){
case "Address":
//set response variable
$ret_s['response'] = 0;
// select organization address
$sql = "SELECT IFNULL(ID, '--') AS ID,
          IFNULL(Organization, '--') AS Organization,
          IFNULL(Contact_Names, '--') AS Contact_Names,
          IFNULL(City, '--') City,
          IFNULL(Street, '--') AS Street,
          IFNULL(Unit, '--') AS Unit,
          IFNULL(Postal_Code, '--') AS Postal_Code,
          IFNULL(Region, '--') AS Region,
          IFNULL(Country, '--') AS Country,
          IFNULL(ts, '--') AS ts
          FROM `raw_data`";
 // prepare the sql statement
 $stmt_s =  $db->prepare($sql);
 $stmt_s->execute();
 $result = $stmt_s->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 // extract table rows
 foreach($result as $row){
 $ret_d[$row_1] = [
         'Id'=> $row['ID'],
         'Organization' => $row['Organization'],
         'Contact_Names' => $row['Contact_Names'],
         'City'=> $row['City'],
         'Street'=> $row['Street'],
         'Unit' => $row['Unit'],
         'Postal_Code' => $row['Postal_Code'],
         'Region' => $row['Region'],
         'Country'=> $row['Country'],
         'Date'=> $row['ts']
];//end load data from data base
$row_1++;
}//end table data as rows
    break;
```

Javascript init file, case 0 section of ajax response function:

```
function processResult_L(data, textStatus){
// Required Callback Function
//create dom elements for table head and body
//to check variables in dev console remove 'var'(make public)
var $table = $("<table id='display_table'>");
$table.append($('<tbody>'));
//create response array
var response = {};
response = data['status']['response'];
//create row array for building table data
var r = [];
switch(response){
case 0: /*Address case */
// build table header
$table.append($('<tr>')
    .append($('<th>').text('ID'))
    .append($('<th>').text('Organization'))
    .append($('<th>').text('Contact'))
    .append($('<th>').text('City'))
    .append($('<th>').text('Street'))
    .append($('<th>').text('Unit'))
    .append($('<th>').text('Post Code'))
    .append($('<th>').text('Region'))
    .append($('<th>').text('Country'))
    .append($('<th>').text('Date')));
// build table content
for(var i = 0; i < data.table_rows.length; i++) {
r[i] = data.table_rows[i];
$table.append($('<tr>')
    .append($('<td>').text(r[i].Id))
    .append($('<td>').text(r[i].Organization))
    .append($('<td>').text(r[i].Contact_Names))
    .append($('<td>').text(r[i].City))
    .append($('<td>').text(r[i].Street))
    .append($('<td>').text(r[i].Unit))
    .append($('<td>').text(r[i].Postal_Code))
    .append($('<td>').text(r[i].Region))
    .append($('<td>').text(r[i].Country))
    .append($('<td>').text(r[i].Date))
); // end append table content
}  // end build table content
    break;
```

Comment: If you move `IFNULL()` from the SQL query to the jQuery part, you can also set class of the element to something like 'empty', so the null placeholder can be gray, for example... `$table...append($('<td>').addClass(r[i].Street ? 'filled' : 'empty').text(r[i].Street || '--'))`. Also it will lower load on your server.

Comment: Yup, that is the way to do it. Excellent. Thank you Josef Kufner.